# AngularJS use directly json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, charts

I am trying to create charts, using data from MySQL in my JS file.

So :

- I receive data in my JS script calling my PHP file.
- My connection works (PHP).
- I convert datas in JSON.
- I get datas back in my JS file.
- And I can display them into my HTML file/page

With :

```
`<div ng-repeat="x in users" align="center">
          <div class="col-md-4" >
            <div class="showProfile">
               {{x.TotalCall}}
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>`
```

My PHP code :

```
    <?php

  $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbname="callstats";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $query = $dbh->query("SELECT extension, COUNT(*) AS TotalCall, COUNT(CASE WHEN billsec >= 20 THEN billsec END) AS 'moreThanTwenty' FROM pbx GROUP BY extension");
  $query = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $myJson = json_encode($query);
  echo "{\"records\":".$myJson."}";

?>
```

My AngularJS file :

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("php/DBbitrix.php")
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.users = response.data.records;
        });

    var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Dark Grey"],
            datasets: [
                {
                  //data: [angular.forEach($scope.userListe, function(value){console.log(value.TotalCall)})],
                    data: [ angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value,TotalCall){TotalCall + ": " + value})],
                    backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });

});
```

So, in my pieChart, if the data is [20,50,60,80,100] for example, it's going to work.

In my database, I have a TotalCall table with numbers values that I want to use in my "data : []" . 
Because in my HTML, values are correctly displayed, I would like to know how I can dirrectly use the JSON datas in my JS file.

I am trying since 3 days, I found a lot of solutions, for example with angular.foreach, but it doesn't work.
I don't understand why this is so complicated to just use a JSON field.

I tried to display values in the console with :

```
var users = $scope.users;
console.log(users);
console.log("t");
console.log($scope.users);
angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value,TotalCall){console.log(TotalCall + ": " + value.TotalCall);})
console.log(angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value,TotalCall){TotalCall + ": " + value}));
console.log(angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value,TotalCall){value}));
console.log(angular.forEach($scope.users, function (value,TotalCall){value.TotalCall}));
```

But the value is "undefined" and I don't get the data I want.

Sorry if I made mistakes, I am still learning English and it's my first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "{\"records\":".$myJson."}"
```

You're not receiving a JSON. You're receiving a string that represents a JSON. You need to parse it :

```
.then(function(response) {
    var myJson = JSON.parse(response)
    $scope.users = myJson.records;
});
```

Comment: I already tried to parse it, but I have an error and I don't understand why. 
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at pieChart.js:7"

Comment: So, I just find a solution to parse it :
var myJson = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
I have no more errors, but I still don't know how to get the correct data.
Because if I use $scope.users in data:[], nothing happen.
And with  $scope.data.totalcall, I have a error.

Comment: You should try with ```typeof response```. If it's string, you have to parse, if it's object, it's a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

thank you for helping me.

The parse was the first step to solve the problem.
I also did a stupid mistake with the "});" at the wrong place.

So here is my solution, I hope it can help someone !

AngularJS :

```
    //pie
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("php/DBbitrix.php")
    .then(function(response) {
    var myJson = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));

    $scope.users = myJson.data.records;
    $scope.data = [];
    for (var i = 0;i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
    $scope.data.push($scope.users[i].TotalCall);
    }

    //pie
    var ctxP = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctxP, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Dark Grey","Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Dark Grey","Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Grey", "Dark Grey"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data : $scope.data,

                    backgroundColor: ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360","#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360","#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#949FB1", "#4D5360"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774","#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774","#FF5A5E", "#5AD3D1", "#FFC870", "#A8B3C5", "#616774"]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
});
});
```